# Typescript: Override static factory method of parent Class in Child method

Tags: node.js, typescript, oop, dependency-injection, tdd

I'm running into some problems with dependency injection with Typescript. On every Class that I add a factory static method where all dependencies are set. I do this for testing purposes so that I'm still able to use the TDD approach.

Now I'm running into some problems with overriding the factory method of the parent class in a child class. Example:

```
interface DepsA {
  a: string
}

interface DepsB extends DepsA {
  b: Child1
}

class Parent {
  constructor(protected deps: DepsA | DepsB) {}

  public static factory<T extends Parent>() {
    return new this({a: 'This is a nice Dependency'}) as T
  }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {}

class Child2 extends Parent {
  public static factory() {
    return new this({a: 'This is a nice Dependency', b: Child1.factory()})
  }
}

const child1 = Child1.factory<Child1>()
const child2 = Child2.factory()
```

The error what I receive is:

```
[ts]
Class static side 'typeof Child2' incorrectly extends base class static side 'typeof Parent'.
  Types of property 'factory' are incompatible.
    Type '() => Child2' is not assignable to type '<T extends Parent>() => T'.
      Type 'Child2' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

I know why I get the error, but have at this point no idea anymore how to fix it, otherwise than renaming the factory static method in Child2.

**UPDATE:** A Related bug report to this problem, that explains automatically why I use a Generic on the factory method is: [#26298](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26298)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there's a pre-defined [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) called **InstanceType** which could help you to infer the class type from the static member:

```
public static factory<T extends typeof Parent>(this: T) {
    return new this({ a: 'This is a nice Dependency' }) as InstanceType<T>
}
```

Second, if you override a method, static or not, in a child class, it should have a compatible signature, including the generic stuff.

Consequently, your code block could look like this (see in [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20DepsA%20%7B%0D%0Aa%3A%20string%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20DepsB%20extends%20DepsA%20%7B%0D%0Ab%3A%20Child1%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Parent%20%7B%0D%0Aconstructor(public%20deps%3A%20DepsA%20%7C%20DepsB)%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20factory%3CT%20extends%20typeof%20Parent%3E(this%3A%20T)%3A%20InstanceType%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this(%7B%20a%3A%20'This%20is%20a%20nice%20Dependency'%20%7D)%20as%20InstanceType%3CT%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child1%20extends%20Parent%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Child2%20extends%20Parent%20%7B%0D%0Apublic%20static%20factory%3CT%20extends%20typeof%20Parent%3E(this%3A%20T)%3A%20InstanceType%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20this(%7Ba%3A%20'This%20is%20a%20nice%20Dependency'%2C%20b%3A%20Child1.factory()%7D)%20as%20InstanceType%3CT%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20child1%20%3D%20Child1.factory()%0D%0Aconst%20child2%20%3D%20Child2.factory()%0D%0Alet%20test2%20%3D%20child2.deps)):

```
interface DepsA {
    a: string
}

interface DepsB extends DepsA {
    b: Child1
}

class Parent {
    constructor(public deps: DepsA | DepsB) {}

    public static factory<T extends typeof Parent>(this: T) {
        return new this({ a: 'This is a nice Dependency' }) as InstanceType<T>
    }
}

class Child1 extends Parent {}

class Child2 extends Parent {
    public static factory<T extends typeof Parent>(this: T) {
        return new this({a: 'This is a nice Dependency', b: Child1.factory()}) as InstanceType<T>
    }
}

const child1 = Child1.factory()  // Type: Child1
const child2 = Child2.factory()  // Type: Child2
```

From there, returning the proper `deps` type, rather than an union, would also be possible in non static members, using `as this["deps"]`. But you'd have to revamp a bit your code.

Hope it helps ;-)

Comment: Why bother making the method generic if you're just going to assert the child type at the end?