# Typescript: How to reassign static function in child class?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a parent class like so:

```
class SomeClass {

  public someProperty: number | undefined;

  constructor(value: number) {
    this.someProperty = value;
  }

  public on(eventType: string, fn: Function) {

  }
}

class Parent {

  protected static getTransform(value: number) {
    return value + 180;
  }

  public transform: SomeClass;

  constructor(value: number) {
    this.transform = this.createTransform(value);
  }

  protected createTransform(value: number) {
    const transform = new SomeClass(value);
    transform.on('rotate', this.rotate);
    return transform;
  }

  protected rotate(event: any) {
    this.transform.someProperty = Parent.getTransform(event.transform);
  }
}
```

And I need to implement child class that has different logic of transform property calculation. I need something, like so:

```
class Child extends Parent {

  protected static getTransform(value: number) {
    return value + 90;
  }

  constructor(value: number) {
    super(value);
  }
}
```

I haven't faced any errors or something else, but my approach doesn't work, nothing changed. How to implement same? [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgYXFaBvAUD60ADgK4BGIAlsNBEsgAoBO8hyjALgJ4Bc0AdsUSk20AD7RifACbIAZhT7IpAbjwFg8PhHaNiwdvEYAKAG5gQxZLwFC2ASmz4C0dgAsKEAHS0UTFmy5oAF5oMwtkVQIAXzUiMkpqTSNkE2Q%20dgAVTlZebUYFAHMAGmhZPl4AMUl9Ck0HXCcYmJxQSBh6MEY09kcnQmZ2ZH0lGnYwdipoAuRMxjAtWUNEU3NLa0FhRnqnAi72YkY%20UNXkaABqaABGAA4ABkjoZoISckmdeYhFxkReBBR0NqqJwaLQ6PQGYxhNb8Db2RzOFzuLzvBZLYKIjyeYBdcbIDJzVHfFbhOwPJ5EAZDQZSaDY5C4-EfL7LKFWGG2Lbw5wg7QuAmfNEhRQAdzgdABUGJllJOz5TKWniSAHIBrilSU3JjVYMZQi9gcjiiBd8ybF%20vBBsMadrkMlUulePNONsEZrkfzmd46H5WBxOOiOl10p5prN5USUt1PEbmbrHjhmq1MKh3CAacgAB6DaTtTrdXrPSlW0bjSahxmElkndYcl3OfWHY7hc7QACc90asR5YP0hilbJsmzrBAgxF9-bjTTwPPgIGQnhA8AKRhF0BTFDTRgATLdbnYZTggA)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Override static factory method of parent Class in Child method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51745654/typescript-override-static-factory-method-of-parent-class-in-child-method)

Answer (score 1):

> ... protected (which allows access from the same class and its subclasses,
> but not objects of a different class) ...
> [Wiki: OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Data_Abstraction)

To clear the `Member Visibility` concept, here is a demo of your code (Please see the comments):

```
class SomeClass {

  public someProperty: number | undefined;

  constructor(value: number) {
    this.someProperty = value;
  }

  public on(eventType: string, fn: Function) {

  }
}

class Parent {

  protected static getTransform(value: number) {
    return value + 180;
  }

  public transform: SomeClass;

  constructor(value: number) {
    this.transform = this.createTransform(value);
  }

  protected createTransform(value: number) {
    const transform = new SomeClass(value);
    transform.on('rotate', this.rotate);
    return transform;
  }

  protected rotate(event: any) {
    this.transform.someProperty = Parent.getTransform(event.transform);
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {

  protected static getTransform(value: number) {
    return value + 90;
  }

  constructor(value: number) {
    super(value);
  }
}

class Example extends Child {
  constructor(value: number) {
      super(value)
    console.log(`In Example:`, Child.getTransform(700)) // this line will be called when `new Example()`
  }

  public static getTransform(value: number) {
    return Child.getTransform(600); // call parent method which is protected is valid
  }

}

// Example use cases:

console.log(`Call Child:`, Child.getTransform(800)) //  this will throw error:
// Property 'getTransform' is protected and only accessible within class 'Child' and its subclasses.

new Example(700) // inheritance can call parent method which is protected

console.log(`Call Example:`, Example.getTransform(1000)) // a function call that call parent protected method is ok.
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgYXFaBvAUD60ADgK4BGIAlsNBEsgAoBO8hyjALgJ4Bc0AdsUSk20AD7RifACbIAZhT7IpAbjwFg8PhHaNiwdvEYAKAG5gQxZLwFC2ASmz4C0dgAsKEAHS0UTFmy5oAF5oMwtkVQIAXzUiMkpqTSNkE2Q+dgAVTlZebUYFAHMAGmhZPl4AMUl9Ck0HXCcYmJxQSBh6MEY09kcnQmZ2ZH0lGnYwdipoAuRMxjAtWUNEU3NLa0FhRnqnAi72YkY+UNXkaABqaABGAA4ABkjoZoISckmdeYhFxkReBBR0NqqJwaLQ6PQGYxhNb8Db2RzOFzuLzvBZLYKIjyeYBdcbIDJzVHfFbhOwPJ5EAZDQZSaDY5C4-EfL7LKFWGG2Lbw5wg7QuAmfNEhRQAdzgdABUGJllJOz5TKWniSAHIBrilSU3JjVYMZQi9gcjiiBd8ybF+vBBsMadrkMlUulePNONsEZrkfzmd46H5WBxOOiOl10p5prN5USUt1PEbmbrHjhmq1MKh3CAacgAB6DaTtTrdXrPSlW0bjSahxmElkndYcl3OfWHY7hc7QACc90asR5YP0hilbJsmzrBAgxF9-bjTTwSZgAFEM2BEIQQKdM9mpDAUxQ01zu7pe5Dq+yh1yEaPx6y7LKefAV54QPACkYAAYASSO88Xy6sz5KW7TIYzBWxrLAA7Lctx2A4AD00EYjAlCKNAwrbiA0DCLS5grjSwquGk0DPiK0CfkuK5GHYz6dn08STNopbUOWHpLP2NYnrgeozAa0D-lIgFhpWRgAGwQaS0CwZhIBoYQebpNAKBuPAOHuMArjQB4FIWlSIzqWEFBSFRzTiSR34SBApzAJAyAQNw06aLQd4Pk+z6oFh3GplI3C-m5268Yx4bLHckEwXB8HIahiLMKKbDMIwNniT6AT+kqfmVkqakwOalrUtA8w0poID+mAwDAFZEAUOQpwoZqRwztASo8WluVqewMCjqQM5WZ4eBEcZZHgZBYlwQoeH5GMfAlZhNWudJQY9PJriKchymqepmVafpLR2beyD3o+L4uZJxELqRP4lL1O0pSBRiXBBQWDTlpTVBMmgSWhbjjK9RAyT0a3FvNi3qfAADWXVAA) <- You can click the `Run` button the see the result and the `Errors` tab to see the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to reassign a static function.. in your case you should override the `rotate()` function in Child and use the Child static method instead:

```
  protected rotate(event: any) {
    this.transform.someProperty = Child.getTransform(event.transform);
  }
```